# Ansible fetch file from windows machine to local ansible machine

Tags: ansible

I am attempting to fetch a zip file from a windows machine to the local ansible machine to later be unzipped and committed to our SCM.

I am wondering if it is possible to fetch files from a windows src to the ansible local machine...

I have previously done the inverse of this using a win_copy and specifying remote_src: no, but I'm not sure if it works the other way around.

```
    - name: "Fetch the file from the src to tower"
      fetch:
        src: "C:/backup.zip"
        dest: "{{ ansible_tmp_path }}/backup.zip"
      delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
```

This is what I have come up with so far but it fails with this output

```
[$remote_host_name]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "src": "C:/backup.zip"
        }
    },
    "msg": "file not found: C:/backup.zip"
}
```

Comment: `delegate_to: 127.0.0.1` makes the task fetch the file from your controller (i.e. your tower instance if I believe the task description). Just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `delagate_to: 127.0.0.1` .

Since you are delegating the task to the localhost its searching for `"C:/backup.zip"` in your ansible tower machine .

Comment: Why `if the hosts.....`? Delegation to localhost must be removed. It's a typo here.

Comment: Agreed . My bad . Edited my answer